# Increased memory usage with frequent useState calls in React Native Mobile application

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, xcode, react-native

In my React Native(JavaScript/TypeScript) mobile app, I have a component where I utilize the useState hook to update data every second. However, after running for 2 hours, the app exceeds its memory usage, leading to crashes in the iOS app when observed through Xcode.

The application crashes without giving any output.

For instance, when I set a constant variable, the memory usage remains stable:

`setData(1);`

But when I replace the data with different values, the memory usage starts to increase:

`setData(previousData => previousData + 1);`

OR

`let test = Math.random(); setData(test);`

How can I prevent or control the memory increase? Are there any optimizations I can apply to reduce memory usage with useState? Thanks.